# ses error : "It must be within 300 secs" clocks are in sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Suddenly my ses mail started giving error.

"It must be within 300 secs"  sync

From forums at first glance it looked servertime and ses mail server time not in sync.  but i verified both are in sync.

```
$date;wget -S "https://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
Mon Jan  7 02:45:04 UTC 2013 <---Local server time 
--2013-01-07 02:45:04--  https://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ <---email server time
<snipped>
```

Any clue why this error?

Comment: Thanks both are diff by few minutes.  Running ntpd Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp you see is from wget and is the local time on the machine where you issued the command. Down below in the part you snipped away you will likely find some headers stating the time of the remote machine, something like `Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2013 03:23:00 GMT`.

Comment: in my /etc/ntp.conf file server [0,1,2,3].debian.pool.ntp.org iburst  is configured.  running ntpdate is telling the NTP socket is in use, exiting.   do i need to sync with ses server time? if yes, with which server i should sync? so i can add that entry in my ntp.conf file?

Comment: Use either `ntp` or `ntpdate`. `ntpd` is a daemon and will constantly keep your time in sync, while `ntpdate` is more useful for one-time updates. If the timediff is large, it can take `ntpd` some time to adjust it (the adjustment will be continously, with a clock running slower or faster as required). In that case, stop `ntpd`, make a one-time run of `ntpdate` and restart `ntpd`.

Comment: @SvenW: That's no longer needed. `ntpd` has known how to do a correct initial time adjustment for several years now.